# How to check actual connection pool in use in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have NodeJS API using mongoose to talk to Mongo DB. Initially, I had the default connection pool size of 5 and later increased it to 20 during performance testing. However, it's bothering me if there is a way to log the actual number of DB instances being used. It could be 10 or 15. But there is no way to figure it out. Has anyone tried to solve this? 
I also came across an article that said that NodeJS uses threads internally (max 4) that would restrict the actual DB threads. Will update this question with the link later.

Comment: You can tail the mongod.log file see the actual connections come and go.

Comment: @JohnnyHK it's not the connections that I am interested in. I have only one DB connection set up from mongoose to DB. It's the pool size in actual use, i want to see.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as a Mongoose (logical) connection is a connection pool. If mongoose is your only connection, then the MongoDB connection count == the mongoose connection's pool size.

Comment: You're correct @JohnnyHK. The connection count in mongo DB is mongoose connection pool size. My interpretation was that 1 mongoose connection is 1 mongo DB connection and the mongoose pool is collection of instances communicating over the single connection pipeline. I just did a test and found myself wrong. Will update with detailed answer later. Thanks though!

Comment: But does it mean all connections are being used ? If I configure pool size = 50, would mongoose utilize the all 50 connections?

Comment: If you had 50 concurrent queries outstanding, yes.